# Transaction is not rolling back in spring batch item writer

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-batch, itemwriter

Transaction is not rolling back in spring batch. I am throwing exception intentionally to test transaction roll back. Database transaction is committing even with exception thrown from the item writer.Below is the method in writer which is saving into DB. compEvent object is jpa repository injected into this class

```
    private void writeCEs(Map> agentMap) throws FailedCompensationException, Exception {

        for (Entry> agent : agentMap.entrySet()) {
            agent.getValue().stream().forEach((ce) -> {
                compEvent.save(ce);
            });
            updateRecordFileStatus(agent.getKey());
            //postToAccounting(agent.getKey(), agent.getValue());
        }
        throw new Exception("Testing XA roolback.... ");
     }
```

I tried marking transaction for the above method with 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
Still it is committing the transaction. I am sure I am missing something. any help would be appreciated.

Below is my batch configuration

```
       @EnableBatchProcessing
        @EnableTransactionManagement @Configuration @ComponentScan({ "com.pm.*" })

    public class TrueBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    EventReader reader;

    @Autowired
    private EventProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    private EventWriter writer;

    @Bean
    protected Step step1(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor) {
        DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
        attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
        attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.DEFAULT.value());     
        attribute.setTimeout(30);

        return steps.get("step1")., Map>>chunk(10).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).transactionAttribute(attribute).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "firstBatchJob")
    public Job job(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
        return jobs.get("firstBatchJob").start(step1).build();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using? You said `compEvent object is jpa repository` so it looks like you are using JPA. In that case, I'm expecting you are configuring Spring Batch to use a `JpaTransactionManager` for your step. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I am using JpaTransactionManager

Comment: MySQL with MyISAM tables perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

According to your configuration, Spring Batch is not configured to use your `JpaTransactionManager`, you need to override `getTransactionManager`, see example [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig). In your case it should be something like:

```
public class TrueBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

   // .. 

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(); // TODO set entity manager factory
    }

}
```

Comment: I have separate trasaction manager for db and trasaction manager looks like this. @Bean
 public PlatformTransactionManager trueDSTransactionManager(
   @Qualifier("trueDSFactory") EntityManagerFactory batchCommEntityManagerFactory) {
  return new JpaTransactionManager(batchCommEntityManagerFactory);
 }  Actually, this problem got solved by creating a separate service and calling this service from writer. I included all my writes in that service. Now I see trasaction is rolling back. Event XA  transaction is also working with separate service.